# Aggregate/collapse data frame

Tags: r, aggregate

Is there an "all-in-one" convenience function in R that can collapse/aggregate a data frame to resolve the many-to-many problem? The motivation is to reduce many-to-many relationships so that two or more tables can be joined on some primary key (a column with unique identifier values). To elucidate, consider a data frame like:

```
set.seed(1) # for reproducibility
df <- data.frame(id = sort(rep(seq(1,3),4)), # primary key
           geo_loc = state.abb[sample(seq(1,length(state.name)), # state abbreviations
                           size=length(sort(rep(seq(1,3),4))), 
                           replace = TRUE)],
           revenue = c(sample(seq(0,50),size=3), sample(c(seq(101,200)),size=3),
                          sample(seq(201,300),size=4), sample(seq(301,1000),size=2)),
           prod_id = sample(LETTERS[c(seq(1,4))],size=12, replace=TRUE),
           quant = c(sample(seq(0,5),size=4), sample(c(seq(3,8)),size=4),
                        sample(seq(6,11),size=2), sample(seq(9,14),size=2))) ; df

   id geo_loc revenue prod_id quant
1   1      MN      47       D     0
2   1      MA      29       B     3
3   1      SD      50       B     4
4   1      NM     174       A     1
5   2      NC     136       D     6
6   2      LA     143       B     5
7   2      IN     215       C     8
8   2      WY     202       A     4
9   3      NY     271       A    10
10  3      HI     211       C     9
11  3      CT     613       C    10
12  3      MS     748       A    14
```

Does a function already exist that will collapse this table such that there is only one row per unique `id`? It would have to convert the `geo_loc` and `prod_id` columns to `k` levels - 1 dummy columns. It would also be nice if such a function could allow automatic clustering of the `revenue` into a number of blocks based on perhaps quantiles.

Comment: I doubt there's a ready-made function that does that. In base R it can be done easily with `split` + `lapply` + `rbind`.  Alternatively you can try a package such as `dplyr` that provides tools for that sort of operations.

Answer (score 0):

Only aggregate when you have a proper grouping variable. It would be more logical to aggregate by `prod_id`, for example.

To perform these data tidying and aggregating operations I would personally recommend `spread()` and `gather()` from the `tidyr` package and `summarise()` and `group_by()` from the `dplyr` package.